# Gulp imagemin prints error because it affects not only .png files

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin, imagemin

Gulp imagemin prints error because it affects `.svg` files along with `.png` images.

**The error is:**

> ```
> [19:37:49] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
> events.js:167
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: Unsupported file type: image/svg+xml
>     at doParse (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\get-pixels\node-pixels.js:126:10)
>     at getPixels (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\get-pixels\node-pixels.js:140:5)
>     at handleFileBuffer (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\pixelsmith\lib\engine.js:45:13)
>     at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\pixelsmith\node_modules\concat-stream\index.js:36:43)
>     at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
>     at finishMaybe (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\pixelsmith\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:475:14)
>     at afterWrite (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\pixelsmith\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:361:3)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at done (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:202:25)
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:139:7
>     at handleImages (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\lib\gulp-spritesmith.js:196:16)
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3694:9
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:359:16
>     at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:933:13)
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:843:16
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3691:13
>     at apply (C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)
>     at C:\Users\ndruce\Desktop\Проекты\revton\node_modules\gulp.spritesmith\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12
> ```

**Gulp part of code:**

```
gulp.task('img:build', function () {
    gulp.src('src/img/**/*.{png}')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

What is the solution for this problem? I just want to recursively optimize `.png` images.

Comment: If you want only.png files you don't need the brackets in the gulp.src('src/img/**/*.png') is enough.  See if that helps.

Comment: @Mark, the same result